# Accessing nested hash values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have hash:

```
request = {"AutoCreate"=>{"Response"=>{"Status"=>"OK", "StatusCode"=>"0", "TransactionStatus"=>"SUCCEEDED", "TransactionReference"=>"MxhRNvs5EuJLTEkhKqO5Olgk2zMtYMTOI0IvQInWPV8EYsWAI7Aji09B3B8Bigzkee20e3bc4bd9eab997d7825b883b7359"}}}
```

How can I access the hash values of `"Status"`, `"StatusCode"`, and `"TransactionStatus"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result["AutoCreate"]["Response"]["Status"]
result["AutoCreate"]["Response"]["StatusCode"]
result["AutoCreate"]["Response"]["TransactionStatus"]
```

Comment: When I have to go through nested hashes I usually use `fetch` to get an error back rather than `nil`. But it's just a preference :)

Comment: @sawa Thank you, i had just figured it out. Indeed am tired.

Answer (score 2):

To access Status

```
result['AutoCreate']['Response']['Status']
```

to access StatusCode

```
result['AutoCreate']['Response']['StatusCode']
```

and TransactionStatus

```
result['AutoCreate']['Response']['TransactionStatus']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vals_to_get = ["Status", "StatusCode", "TransactionStatus"]
p request["AutoCreate"]["Response"].values_at(*vals_to_get) #=> ["OK", "0", "SUCCEEDED"]
```